# Frame.navigate and NagivationService do not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I don't know why Frame.Navigate and NavigationService don't work.

Here my following code, 
MainPage.xaml :

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />

    <Button
        Command="{Binding ConnexionViewCommand}"
        x:Name="Connexion_button" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="90,308,0,0"
        Content="Login" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="282"/>
    <Button 
        Command="{Binding InscriptionViewCommand}"
        x:Name="Create_account" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="90,446,0,0"
        Content="Create Account" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="282"/>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    readonly static ConnexionViewModel _ConnexionViewModel = new ConnexionViewModel();
    readonly static InscriptionViewModel _InscriptionViewModel = new InscriptionViewModel();
    readonly static MainPageViewModel _MainPageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();


    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
    public ICommand ConnexionViewCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand InscriptionViewCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel._MainPageViewModel;
        ConnexionViewCommand =  new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteConnexionViewCommand());
        InscriptionViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteInscriptionViewCommand());
    }

    private void ExecuteConnexionViewCommand()
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(ConnexionView));
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ConnexionView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        MessageBox.Show("CONNEXION");
    }

    private void ExecuteInscriptionViewCommand()
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(InscriptView));
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/InscriptionView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        MessageBox.Show("REGISTER");
    }
```

I have this following error for my Frame.navigate : Cannot Convert System.String to System.Uri.

For my NavigationService.Navigate : An object reference is required for the property. The method or the non-static field "NavigationService.Navigate (Uri)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix Frame.nagivate and NavigationService.Navigate together.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different things together

This `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ConnexionView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));` is common approach in Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 Silverlight.

This is approach used at Windows Phone 8.1 : `Frame.Navigate(typeof(ConnexionView));`

In your case Frame.Navigate is not an option, just delete that line.

Comment: i try the two lines to try to change the view on click(the message.box work so the function is called). But both of them ( frame.navigate and NavigationService) didn't work.
how can i fixe that?

Comment: Probably you have something wrong with NavigationService

Comment: do i add some code for NavigationService? its not a lib?